# Octave - Mark zero crossings with an red X mark

Tags: graph, plot, octave

Hi have made this code to plot a function.

**I need to mark with an red X all the crossings between x = 0 and the blue wave line in the graph.**

I have made some tries but with '-xr' in the plot function but it places X marks out of the crossings.

Anyone knows how to do it. Many thanks.

**Code:**

```
% entrada
a = input('Introduza o valor de a: ');
% ficheiro fonte para a função
raizes; 
% chamada à função
x = 0:.1:50;
or = x;
or(:) = 0;
h = @(x) cos(x);
g = @(x) exp(a*x)-1;
f = @(x) h(x) - g(x);
zeros = fzero(f,0);
plot(x,f(x));
hold on
plot(zeros,f(zeros),'-xr')
hold off
```

**Graph (it only marks one zero, i need all the zero crossings):**

[image]

Comment: You have to find the crossings mathematically first.

Comment: mathematically? is there a formula for that?

Comment: Yes? Set `f(x) = 0`, solve for `x`...

Comment: Alternatively, look for sign changes in your data to see where it crosses the `x` axis. Note that this will not yield an exact solution and the accuracy will increase as `dx` decreases.

Comment: I used:
zeros = fzero(f,0);
 plot(x,f(x));
 hold on
 plot(zeros,f(zeros),'-xr')
 hold off

But only marks one zero :(

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Solvers.html#XREFfzero). `fzero` attempts to find the zero closest to the starting point (or inside the provided interval). You will need to iterate `fzero` in order to find multiple zeros.

Comment: Yes, i suspected it was done that way. But i don't know how to iterate fzero. I edited the post above for the code and the plot output.

Comment: Tried to make a for loop but it didn´t work ->  for i=0:length(x);
 or = x;
 or(:) = 0;
 zeros = fzero(f,0);
 end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you need to look for the zeros of your function before you can plot them. You can do this mathematically (in this case set `f(x) = g(x)` and solve for x) or you can do this analytically with something like [`fsolve`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Solvers.html#XREFfsolve).

If you read the documentation for `fsolve`, you will see that it searches for the zero closest to the provided `x0` if passed a scalar or the first zero if passed an interval. What we can do for a quick attempt at a solution is to pass our `x` values into `fsolve` as initial guesses and filter out the unique values.

```
% Set up sample data
a = .05;
x = 0:.1:50;

% Set up equations
h = @(x) cos(x);
g = @(x) exp(a*x)-1;
f = @(x) h(x) - g(x);

% Find zeros of f(x)
crossingpoints = zeros(length(x), 1); % Initialize array
for ii = 1:length(x) % Use x data points as guesses for fzero
    try
      crossingpoints(ii) = fzero(f, x(ii)); % Find zero closest to guess
    end
end
crossingpoints(crossingpoints < 0) = []; % Throw out zeros where x < 0

% Find unique zeros
tol = 10^-8;
crossingpoints = sort(crossingpoints(:)); % Sort data for easier diff
temp = false(size(crossingpoints)); % Initialize testing array

% Find where the difference between 'zeros' is less than or equal to the
% tolerance and throw them out
temp(1:end-1) = abs(diff(crossingpoints)) <= tol; 
crossingpoints(temp) = [];

% Sometimes catches beginning of the data set, filter it out if this happens
if abs(f(crossingpoints(1))) >= (0 + tol)
    crossingpoints(1) = [];
end

% Plot data
plot(x, f(x))
hold on
plot(crossingpoints, f(crossingpoints), 'rx')
hold off
grid on
axis([0 20 -2 2]);
```

Which gives us the following:

[image: yay]

Note that due to [errors arising from floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) we have to utilize a tolerance to filter our zeros rather than utilizing a function like [`unique`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Sets.html).

Comment: Many thanks. Great piece of code. But it gives error when testing -> error: script: A(I,J): row index out of bounds; value 501 out of bound 1

Comment: The error is located at -> crossingpoints = zeros(length(x), 1);

Comment: Any solution? I can't solve the error. It only disappears when the x value = only one scalar value. With an interval it is always wrong.

Comment: With some minor modifications in your code i manage to keep it working as i wanted. Many thanks. the answer is very good and i wiil accept it as correct :)